# Nav, Subnav and Sidenav fixed, while body scrolls

Tags: html, css

I'm using angular and need to create fixed `nav` and `subnav` and sidebar.

How can I do on bootstrap double lines on top fixed and sidebar too and `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` can be scrolled.

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<app-subnavbar></app-subnavbar>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is an image of what I want:

[image]

Comment: make your questions more clear

Comment: I completed the HTML sample to be well-formed. I also incorporated the image.

Comment: @nikhilsugandh thx but still no answare :(

Comment: show us whta you have tried ??